# How to make the use of tikzexternalize and saveboxes compatible?

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes, tikz-external

In order to build complex `tizkpictures`, I use `savebox`es to "import" sub-parts of my figure.
It works great, except when I want to externalize the computation of my figures. In this case, compilation succeed, but I get the following error in my figures (there should be an imported drawing within the orange-filled-with-red-border node):
[image]

**Question:** How to enable the externalization of `tikzpictures` with the use of `savebox`es?

---

**MWE** (works great until you uncomment `\tikzexternalize`)

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{external}
%       \tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
    %savebox definition
    \newsavebox{\myBox}
    \begin{lrbox}{\myBox}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{lrbox}
    %drawing the picture
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw = red, fill = orange] {\usebox{\myBox}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: *[tikzexternalize and savebox error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/295907/64454) seems a pretty similar question, but suggested solution (*"put[ing] the definition of [the savebox] after `\begin{document}`"*) obviously does not work in the MWE above. (Same solution accepted in [pgfmathdeclarefunction with savebox and tikzexternalize: tikzpicture optimized away](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296259/64454))*.

Edit: It doesn't work neither when the  `savebox` is defined within the main `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: If putting them after `\begin{document}` does not help, did you try to put them after `\begin{tikzpicture}`?

Comment: @Symbol1 It works only if there is no `tikzpicture` environment in the savebox (i.e. `\tikz` commands only). I've updated the MWE accordingly.

Comment: it can probably be made to work but why bother? If you are externalizing the images then they are just re-imported as a single chunk of pdf anyway so nothing saved by boxing them.

Comment: Good point. But what is the difficulty for you to use `\begin{tikzpicture}` instead of `\tikz{}`? As long as I can tell they are the same. (except you have verbatim/listings things inside, of course.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am actually importing several "chunks" in a main figure, and then add some elements using nodes defined in some of these saveboxes. I thus cannot simply include pdf images instead.

Comment: @Symbol1 No real reasons: it's only because the boxed code is pretty large (a few hundred lines, with liberal line breaks) that I used an environment rather than one huge macro running over multiple lines (and because I wasn't aware one can pass options to the `\tikz` command!).

Comment: But what is the point of the saveboxes?

Comment: @cfr It is used for [nesting several elements](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/362307/64454) (notably two matrices).

Comment: @ebo But that doesn't explain why you can't include them as images.

Comment: @cfr I actually want to later refer to nodes defined within the imported "sub-picture" (e.g. an arrow between `(submatrixA-1-1)` and `(submatrixB-2-1)`, where both "sub-matrices" are imported in single boxes as nodes of a "macro-matrix"), and I thought I would not be possible if I import them as pdf (i.e. one could not use coordinates of imported figures anymore).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Edit

In light of the fact that the OP needs to access coordinates within the nested pictures, I recommend using [Symbol 1's `\scopenode` solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362360/). However, as it stands, any fill in the enclosing node will obliterate the content.

However, you can modify the macro to put the contents of the enclosing node behind the material it encloses. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external,backgrounds}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzset{external/prefix=ffigurau/}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarelayer{scopenode}
\pgfsetlayers{background,scopenode,main}
\tikzset{%
  % adapted from tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarybackgrounds.code.tex
  on scopenode layer/.style={%
    execute at begin scope={%
      \pgfonlayer{scopenode}%
      \let\tikz@options=\pgfutil@empty%
      \tikzset{every on scopenode layer/.try,#1}%
      \tikz@options%
    },
    execute at end scope={\endpgfonlayer}
  },
}
% ateb Symbol 1: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362360/
\newbox\tikz@sand@box
\newcount\tikz@scope@depth
\tikz@scope@depth111\relax
\def\scopenode[#1]#2{% name=<enw>, at=<man>, anchor=<angor>
  \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}%
    \advance\tikz@scope@depth111\relax%
    % process the user option
    \begin{scope}[name=tempscopenodename,at={(0,0)},anchor=center,#1]%
      % try to extract positioning information: name, at, anchor
      \global\let\tikz@fig@name\tikz@fig@name%
      \global\let\tikz@node@at\tikz@node@at%
      \global\let\tikz@anchor\tikz@anchor%
    \end{scope}%
    \let\tikz@scopenode@name\tikz@fig@name%
    \let\tikz@scopenode@at\tikz@node@at%
    \let\tikz@scopenode@anchor\tikz@anchor%
    % try to typeset this scope
    % we only need bounding box information
    % the box itself will be discard
    \setbox\tikz@sand@box=\hbox{%
      \begin{scope}[local bounding box=tikz@sand@box\the\tikz@scope@depth,#1]%
        #2%
      \end{scope}%
    }%
    % goodbye. haha
    \setbox\tikz@sand@box=\hbox{}%
    % now typeset again
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=\tikz@scopenode@name]%
      % use the bounding box information to reposition the scope
      \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{tikz@sand@box\the\tikz@scope@depth}{\tikz@scopenode@anchor}%
        \pgf@x-\pgf@x\pgf@y-\pgf@y}%
      \pgftransformshift{\tikz@scopenode@at}%
      \begin{scope}[#1]%
        #2
      \end{scope}%
    \end{scope}%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/freeze local bounding box=\tikz@scopenode@name}%
    \global\let\tikz@scopenode@name@smuggle\tikz@scopenode@name%
  \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}%
  % make up the bounding box
  \path(\tikz@scopenode@name@smuggle.south west)(\tikz@scopenode@name@smuggle.north east);%
  % draw something, not necessary
  \begin{scope}[on scopenode layer]%
    \draw[#1](\tikz@scopenode@name@smuggle.south west)rectangle(\tikz@scopenode@name@smuggle.north east);%
  \end{scope}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw [blue] circle (5pt);
  \scopenode[draw=red, fill=orange, name=bob, at={(2,2)}, anchor=south west]{%
    \draw (0,0) coordinate (a) -- (1,1) coordinate (b);
  }
  \scopenode[draw=blue, fill=yellow, name=gog, at={(-2,-2)}, anchor=north east]{%
    \draw [magenta] (1,1) coordinate (c) -- (0,0) coordinate (d);
  }
  \draw [->] (a) [bend right] to (c);
  \draw [->] (d) [bend right] to (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: <code>\scopenode</code> with layering]

## Original Answer & Explanation

When compiling externalised images, Ti*k*Z ignores all other pictures in the document (and 'expensive' commands, as well). This is designed to speed compilation by 'optimising away' irrelevant, but resource-hungry typesetting tasks.

You can always switch it off if you really need to do things this way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzset{%
  external/prefix=ffigurau/,
  external/optimize=false,
}
\begin{document}
%savebox definition
\newsavebox{\myBox}
\begin{lrbox}{\myBox}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{lrbox}
%drawing the picture
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw = red, fill = orange] {\usebox{\myBox}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, if you have many pictures (and why else would you want to use externalisation?) this will greatly slow compilation whenever a picture needs to be compiled. For each new or changed picture, all pictures will be compiled and all 'expensive' commands executed.

I don't see why you can't do the following instead. This code uses the save box, but only to prevent the picture being typeset in the main document. Otherwise, the save box is simply ignored.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzset{%
  external/prefix=ffigurau/,
}
\begin{document}
%savebox definition
\newsavebox{\myBox}
\tikzsetnextfilename{mybox}
\begin{lrbox}{\myBox}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{lrbox}
%drawing the picture
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw = red, fill = orange] {\includegraphics{ffigurau/mybox}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It makes no sense to say you can't include the image here as that is literally what you are doing when you externalise it anyway. (The save box effectively just does `\includegraphics{...}` and then you `\usebox{...}`, so you might just as well `\includegraphics{...}` directly.

Comment: You basically detail two solutions: **(1)** disabling externalization (either globally, or on a ad-hoc basis as you explained [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/284677/64454) (my bad, I found this question only later)). It works great, but in that case you lose benefits of externalization. Or **(2)** including saveboxes as pdf images. In this case however, one cannot later use (in the main tikzpicture) coordinates defined in the savebox (yet I want to access them - it was however not made explicit in my question). So I have solution for each case, even if not optimal (extern+reusing coord).

Comment: @ebo Neither solution disables externalisation either locally or globally. The first solution disables optimisation of externalisation, but it does not disable externalisation.

Comment: @ebo If you need access to the coordinates, why aren't you using the `\scopenode` solution?

Comment: @ebo It is one of the answers to your earlier question. It was written to address the particular issue you raised. I didn't try it, but it looked to be by far the most sophisticated answer there and its author is certainly an expert on PGF/Ti*k*Z.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56939/discussion-between-ebo-and-cfr).

Comment: @ebo Please see edit above.