# TikZ: Make "scopenode" compatible with matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-matrix, scoping

**Context:** This question is a follow-up of [Best practice for creating TikZ pictures with nested elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/362307/64454). *Symbol 1* provided [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362360/64454) to this question, where `\scopenode` is defined.

`\scopenode` are scopes turned into nodes, i.e. one can: name the scope by `name=foo`; position the scope by `at=(somewhere)`; and tune the position by `anchor=something`. They are basically awesome, since they can be nested.

Then, in [How to make the use of tikzexternalize and saveboxes compatible?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/364135/64454), *cfr* provided [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/364162/64454) improving these `\scopenode`s by enabling the display of both `\scopenode`'s background and the content of the `\scopenode`. (Scopenode background would indeed be drawn *above* the content otherwise.)

**Problem:** I tried to include `\scopenode` in a Ti*k*Z `matrix`. However, I have some issues:

- with Symbol 1's solution, `\scopenode`s are well positioned, but their content do not appear because it's hidden behind the fill color.
  [image]
- with cfr's solution, content is shown (and well positioned), but `\scopenode`s get messed up.
  [image]

**Question:** How to make `\scopenode` compatible with Ti*k*Z `matrix`?

---

**MWEs**
(The example creates a matrix with *one* row and two columns. In both cells (A1 and B1), a scopenope is filled-drawn. A (red-orange) is south anchored, and B (yellow-green) is north anchored. In each scopenode, a path is drawn from (0,0) to (1,1)).

```
 _______
| A |   |
|---|---|  <-- baseline
|___|_B_|
```

*With Symbol 1's solution:*

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix} 
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} 
% \usetikzlibrary{external} 
% \tikzexternalize 
% \tikzset{external/prefix=build/} 

\makeatletter 
\newbox\tikz@sand@box 
\newcount\tikz@scope@depth 
\tikz@scope@depth111\relax 
\def\scopenode[#1]#2{% 
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}% 
\advance\tikz@scope@depth111\relax% 
% process the user option 
\begin{scope}[name=tempscopenodename,at={(0,0)},anchor=center,#1]% 
% try to extract positioning information: name, at, anchor 
\global\let\tikz@fig@name\tikz@fig@name% 
\global\let\tikz@node@at\tikz@node@at% 
\global\let\tikz@anchor\tikz@anchor% 
\end{scope}% 
\let\tikz@scopenode@name\tikz@fig@name% 
\let\tikz@scopenode@at\tikz@node@at% 
\let\tikz@scopenode@anchor\tikz@anchor% 
% try to typeset this scope 
% we only need bounding box information 
% the box itself will be discard 
\setbox\tikz@sand@box=\hbox{% 
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=tikz@sand@box\the\tikz@scope@depth,#1]% 
#2% 
\end{scope}% 
}% 
% goodbye. haha 
\setbox\tikz@sand@box=\hbox{}% 
% now typeset again 
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=\tikz@scopenode@name]% 
% use the bounding box information to reposition the scope 
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{tikz@sand@box\the\tikz@scope@depth}{\tikz@scopenode@anchor}% 
\pgf@x-\pgf@x\pgf@y-\pgf@y}% 
\pgftransformshift{\tikz@scopenode@at}% 
\begin{scope}[#1]% 
#2 
\end{scope}% 
\end{scope}% 
\pgfkeys{/pgf/freeze local bounding box=\tikz@scopenode@name}% 
\global\let\tikz@scopenode@name@smuggle\tikz@scopenode@name% 
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}% 
% make up the bounding box 
\path(\tikz@scopenode@name@smuggle.south west)(\tikz@scopenode@name@smuggle.north east);% 
% draw something, not necessary 
\draw[#1](\tikz@scopenode@name@smuggle.south west)rectangle(\tikz@scopenode@name@smuggle.north east);% 
} 
\makeatother 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[ 
remember picture, 
inner sep=0pt, 
outer sep=0pt, 
] 
\draw [help lines](-2,-2) grid (2,2); 
\matrix[ 
column sep=2em, 
row sep = 1em, 
nodes in empty cells, 
anchor=center, 
nodes={anchor=center}, 
] 
{ 
\scopenode[draw = red, fill = orange, anchor=south] { 
\draw [blue] (0,0) -- (1,1); 
}; 
& 
\scopenode[draw = yellow, fill = green, anchor=north] { 
\draw [black] (0,1) -- (1,0); 
}; 
\\ 
}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

*With cfr's solution:*

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{matrix} 
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds} 
% \usetikzlibrary{external} 
% \tikzexternalize 
% \tikzset{external/prefix=build/} 

\makeatletter 
\pgfdeclarelayer{scopenode} 
\pgfsetlayers{background,scopenode,main} 
\tikzset{% 
% adapted from tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarybackgrounds.code.tex 
on scopenode layer/.style={% 
execute at begin scope={% 
\pgfonlayer{scopenode}% 
\let\tikz@options=\pgfutil@empty% 
\tikzset{every on scopenode layer/.try,#1}% 
\tikz@options% 
}, 
execute at end scope={\endpgfonlayer} 
}, 
} 
% ateb Symbol 1: tex.stackexchange.com/a/… 
\newbox\tikz@sand@box 
\newcount\tikz@scope@depth 
\tikz@scope@depth111\relax 
\def\scopenode[#1]#2{% name=<enw>, at=<man>, anchor=<angor> 
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}% 
\advance\tikz@scope@depth111\relax% 
% process the user option 
\begin{scope}[name=tempscopenodename,at={(0,0)},anchor=center,#1]% 
% try to extract positioning information: name, at, anchor 
\global\let\tikz@fig@name\tikz@fig@name% 
\global\let\tikz@node@at\tikz@node@at% 
\global\let\tikz@anchor\tikz@anchor% 
\end{scope}% 
\let\tikz@scopenode@name\tikz@fig@name% 
\let\tikz@scopenode@at\tikz@node@at% 
\let\tikz@scopenode@anchor\tikz@anchor% 
% try to typeset this scope 
% we only need bounding box information 
% the box itself will be discard 
\setbox\tikz@sand@box=\hbox{% 
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=tikz@sand@box\the\tikz@scope@depth,#1]% 
#2% 
\end{scope}% 
}% 
% goodbye. haha 
\setbox\tikz@sand@box=\hbox{}% 
% now typeset again 
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=\tikz@scopenode@name]% 
% use the bounding box information to reposition the scope 
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{tikz@sand@box\the\tikz@scope@depth}{\tikz@scopenode@anchor}% 
\pgf@x-\pgf@x\pgf@y-\pgf@y}% 
\pgftransformshift{\tikz@scopenode@at}% 
\begin{scope}[#1]% 
#2 
\end{scope}% 
\end{scope}% 
\pgfkeys{/pgf/freeze local bounding box=\tikz@scopenode@name}% 
\global\let\tikz@scopenode@name@smuggle\tikz@scopenode@name% 
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}% 
% make up the bounding box 
\path(\tikz@scopenode@name@smuggle.south west)(\tikz@scopenode@name@smuggle.north east);% 
% draw something, not necessary 
\begin{scope}[on scopenode layer]% 
\draw[#1](\tikz@scopenode@name@smuggle.south west)rectangle(\tikz@scopenode@name@smuggle.north east);% 
\end{scope}% 
} 
\makeatother 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[ 
remember picture, 
inner sep=0pt, 
outer sep=0pt, 
] 
\draw [help lines](-2,-2) grid (2,2); 
\matrix[ 
column sep=2em, 
row sep = 1em, 
nodes in empty cells, 
anchor=center, 
nodes={anchor=center}, 
] 
{ 
\scopenode[draw = red, fill = orange, anchor=south] { 
\draw [blue] (0,0) -- (1,1); 
}; 
& 
\scopenode[draw = yellow, fill = green, anchor=north] { 
\draw [black] (0,1) -- (1,0); 
}; 
\\ 
}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't it *not* well-positioned with my solution? It is shown and it is above the background i.e. it gets onto the right layer. But it is in the wrong place.

Comment: @cfr I meant the *content* of the scopenode (i.e. the drawn line) is well positioned, when the scopenode itself (the filled-drawn square) is not. But my example is tricky: the two scopenodes are on the same row... but one (orange/red) is south-anchored when the second (green/yellow) is north anchored. So it should look like picture 1 + drawn lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by far the best I can get:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
% \usetikzlibrary{external}
% \tikzexternalize
% \tikzset{external/prefix=build/}

\makeatletter
    \newbox\tikz@sand@box
    \newcount\tikz@scope@depth
    \newdimen\tikz@scope@shiftx
    \newdimen\tikz@scope@shifty
    \newdimen\tikz@scope@swx
    \newdimen\tikz@scope@swy
    \newdimen\tikz@scope@nex
    \newdimen\tikz@scope@ney
    \tikz@scope@depth111\relax
    \def\scopenode[#1]#2{%
        \begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}%
            \advance\tikz@scope@depth111\relax%
            % process the user option
            \begin{scope}[name=tempscopenodename,at={(0,0)},anchor=center,#1]%
                % try to extract positioning information: name, at, anchor
                \global\let\tikz@fig@name@\tikz@fig@name%
                \global\let\tikz@node@at@\tikz@node@at%
                \global\let\tikz@anchor@\tikz@anchor%
            \end{scope}%
            \let\tikz@scopenode@name\tikz@fig@name@%
            \let\tikz@scopenode@at\tikz@node@at@%
            \let\tikz@scopenode@anchor\tikz@anchor@%
            % try to typeset this scope
            % we only need bounding box information
            % the box itself will be discard
            \setbox\tikz@sand@box=\hbox{%
                \begin{scope}[local bounding box=tikz@sand@box\the\tikz@scope@depth,#1]%
                    #2%
                \end{scope}%
            }%
            % goodbye. haha
            \setbox\tikz@sand@box=\hbox{}%
            % now typeset again
            \begin{scope}[local bounding box=\tikz@scopenode@name]%
                % use the bounding box information to reposition the scope
                \pgfpointanchor{tikz@sand@box\the\tikz@scope@depth}{\tikz@scopenode@anchor}%
                \tikz@scope@shiftx-\pgf@x%
                \tikz@scope@shifty-\pgf@y%
                \tikz@scopenode@at%
                \advance\tikz@scope@shiftx\pgf@x%
                \advance\tikz@scope@shifty\pgf@y%
                \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\tikz@scope@shiftx}{\tikz@scope@shifty}}
                % the background path
                % lengthy, tedious calculation
                % someone please improve this
                \pgfpointanchor{tikz@sand@box\the\tikz@scope@depth}{south west}
                \tikz@scope@swx\pgf@x\advance\tikz@scope@swx\tikz@scope@shiftx
                \tikz@scope@swy\pgf@y\advance\tikz@scope@swy\tikz@scope@shifty
                \pgfpointanchor{tikz@sand@box\the\tikz@scope@depth}{north east}
                \tikz@scope@nex\pgf@x\advance\tikz@scope@nex\tikz@scope@shiftx
                \tikz@scope@ney\pgf@y\advance\tikz@scope@ney\tikz@scope@shifty
                \path(\tikz@scope@swx,\tikz@scope@swy)coordinate(tempsw)
                     (\tikz@scope@nex,\tikz@scope@ney)coordinate(tempne);
                \path[#1](tempsw)rectangle(tempne);
                % typeset the content for real
                \begin{scope}[#1]%
                    #2%
                \end{scope}%
            \end{scope}%
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/freeze local bounding box=\tikz@scopenode@name}%
            \global\let\tikz@scopenode@name@smuggle\tikz@scopenode@name%
        \end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}%
        % make up the bounding box
        \path(\tikz@scopenode@name@smuggle.south west)(\tikz@scopenode@name@smuggle.north east);%
        % compatible code for matrix
        \expandafter\pgf@nodecallback\expandafter{\tikz@scopenode@name@smuggle}%
    }
\makeatother



\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
        \draw[help lines](-2,-2)grid(2,2);
        \matrix()
        [
            column sep=2em,
            row sep=1em,
            nodes in empty cells,
            anchor=center,
            nodes={anchor=center},
        ]
        {
            \scopenode[draw=red,fill=orange,name=aaa,anchor=south] {
                \draw[blue](0,0)--(1,1)circle(.2);
            };
            &
            \scopenode[draw=yellow,fill=green,name=bbb,anchor=north] {
                \draw[black](0,1)--(1,0)circle(.1);
            };
            &
            \scopenode[fill=cyan,name=ccc,anchor=east,scale=.8] {
                \draw(0,0)--(1,1)circle(.3)--(2,0);
            };
            \\
            \node(aaaa){};
            &
            \node(bbbb){};
            &
            \node(cccc){};
            \\
        };
    \draw[->](2,2)node[above]{this is the orange scopenode}to[bend left](aaa.east);
    \draw[->](-2,-2)node[below]{this is the green scopenode}to[bend left](bbb.west);
    \draw[->](3,-1)node[right]{this is the cyan scopenode}to[bend left](ccc.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Importation information

Dear future me:

For your information, the content of the matrix is typeset only once in a hbox. And then they are moved to the corresponding cell. And then the whole matrix is moved to the desired position. The first movement is done by `\pgf@matrix@shift@nodes@initial` and the second by `\pgf@matrix@shift@nodes@secondary`. They are merely applying `\pgf@shift@node` to a node list. To register the scopenode, you added the line

```
\expandafter\pgf@nodecallback\expandafter{\tikz@scopenode@name@smuggle}%
```

so the scopenode is also moved.

---

Currently everything in the scopenode will be typeset twice. For nested scopenode, things are typeset 2<sup>depth</sup> times. This is really frustrating. Maybe someone can improve this by the way Ti*k*Z deals with matrix.

(However matrix cannot be nested. You win!)

---

---

Also, you changed

```
\global\let\tikz@fig@name\tikz@fig@name
```

to

```
\global\let\tikz@fig@name@\tikz@fig@name
```

so that the name of the scopenode cannot be accessed elsewhere.

In particular, Ti*k*Z will apply `\pgf@shift@node` to the matrix itself. If the matrix is unnamed, then the last scopenode will be shifted, which is unwanted. You spent two hours only to found this stupid bug. LEARN THE LESSON.

---

---

Also, you hardcoded the backgroundpath of the scopenode so that it is now filled/drawn before the content of the scope. (Hence the name **background**path) But the calculation is lengthy and seemingly redundant. I hope someone can improve it.

Nonetheless you avoided using `pgfonlayer`. That is great.